# How do I browse CentOS packages?

Tags: centos, yum, packages

I have been using Debian for some time but am brand new to CentOS. How can I browse CentOS packages in a web browser like I do at packages.debian.org?

If there is no such website, can someone give me a quick command line of how to look up a packages and details (description, software version, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generically speacking

```
yum search "search-string"
```

will search any of your configured and enabled repo's, though its not always handy to use yum / rpm commands if your stuck on something like a .so.* dependency failure.
EDIT: I know the above isn't web, but there are yum GUI's around that emulate that function, I just can never remember a good one so prefer the command line.

For dependencies and as a general goto for rpm searching I use: http://rpm.pbone.net/  click the advanced search link to narrow the search to your distros.

I find this an awesome resource as it doesn't just index the redhat/fedora/suse default repos, though I'm not sure if it includes RPMFusion (which is another great 3rd Party source and is searchable).

Answer (score 0):

CentOS doesn't have such a database as far as I know. You can use Fedora's, they have the same packages available for the most part: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/

Comment: FYI: The following warns against using Fedora RPMs as substitute for CentOS... http://serverfault.com/questions/71299/installing-fedora-rpms-in-centos?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS folks came up with [a guide](http://centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/) for an older version of `yum`, but it should still work.